# using owen-it/laravel-auditing package is there a way to change value from user_id to user_name?

Tags: laravel, package

By default user_id are getting fetched i want to fetch user_name instead is there a way to modify fetch value?

[image]

Only code i use for my **User model**

```
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;


class User extends Authenticatable implements Auditable

use Notifiable;
use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

 protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_type'
];
```

Comment: you question is incomplete. what code you had done till now.

Comment: Why do you want `user_name`, this defeats the purpose of a relational database. If you want the `name` of the user, just perform a `join`.

Comment: i have solution by using join still thank you

Answer (score 0):

go to config/audit.php and modify the user array like below

```
'user' => [
  'primary_key' => 'id',
  'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
    
  // replace the line below
  'model'       => App\User::class,
    
  // with this
  'model'       => App\Models\User::class,
],
```

for more details see this
https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-audit-trail-laravel/